# How can I generate a PDF based on a view in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

#### Overview

I want to generate a PDF based on a view in a Rails app using models I have from within the app itself (i.e. visiting a specific endpoint will render a PDF report).

#### Question

What's a standard/efficient way of doing so?

#### Things I've tried

I've attempted using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), and [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit). Both of which rely on [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org).

But I've faced a few issues:

- Rendering a PDF takes a long time
- Cannot use existing stylesheets because some CSS like `flexbox` isn't supported
- Formatting is off
- ES6 isn't supported
- Debugging Javascript is difficult
- The debug option `show_as_html` for [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) doesn't reliably show you how the PDF renders
- Some JS libraries like ChatJS and Google Maps don't render correctly
- Using `javascript_delay` seems to be a silver bullet, but it doesn't solve issues with 3rd party libraries

There must be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

The only approach I can think of to achieve something like this is to solve the issues you're presenting 1 by 1. In my experience, `wicked_pdf` is the best way to go. Regarding the issues you're presenting:

1. Rendering a PDF takes a long time: You can caché PDFs and save them in your server (either using paperclip, activestorage, shrine, or some other file manager that works with rails). This way the generation of the PDF will only take time once.
2. Cannot use existing stylesheets because some CSS like flexbox isn't supported: As stated by [github this issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522), flexbox isn't fully supported, even though there's a few things that do work, such as  changing `display: flex` for `display: -webkit-box`. If the partial fixed found in that issue do not work, the solution would be to go for a non-flex view for the PDF generation.
3. Formatting is off: This most likely has to do with CSS not working properly due to unsupported CSS properties. You can fix them one by one, they shouldn't be many, as wicked_pdf does support the most common and used CSS properties (flexbox might be an exception)
4. ES6 isn't supported: you're right. You'll have to right normal javascript for these views.
5. Debugging Javascript is difficult: A key takeaway from debugging javascript and understanding how it works, is basically removing every animation possible. For instance, if you're using a library that has a "render animation" (let's say google maps had a fade in effect), wicked_pdf will start rendering google maps once you remove these effects, so that there's no "fade in" nor "delay", otherwise wicked_pdf will take a "screenshot" of the page being rendered at second 0.
6. The debug option show_as_html for wicked_pdf doesn't reliably show you how the PDF renders: Correct, this has to do with (5) and (3).
7. Some JS libraries like ChatJS and Google Maps don't render correctly: As stated in 5, this has to do with "delays"in the render method. There's a new API method supported by wicked_pdf called javascript_delay, which you can find an issue [about here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/397)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but each PDF is different I cannot cache the result, the views I have are already using flexbox and ES6. Even when disabling animations, any issue with JS will break the render. And I'm using javascript_delay, but the issue is still not resolved. Wicked_pdf seems to be the best option, but it's a bit disappointing in 2019.

Comment: @MrHaze I understand. Yes it's a shame that there's still issues rendering PDFs, wicked_pdf hasn't been able to progress as fast as they would want due to lack of funding, so people who are working on it are just working when they have time. I'm sorry that my answer couldn't help you at this time. Based on your requirements, I'd say there's no rails library that will be able to solve your needs, however you could still separate this into a separate microservice a second approach would be to send the already processed HTML to another PDF html-to-pdf library that might work with other technology

Comment: Yeah... As seems to be the issue with quite a few opensource projects.
I've been thinking of using PhantomJS to render the PDF.

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely look into other technologies. For instance if you were to use a python or javascript library, you could build a wrapper around it so that rails sends the file to it and receives a PDF as a result. There might also be freemium online services that might do something like this (I don't know any at this point, but could be an option)

Comment: My advice is to make a separate HTML/CSS/JS/Layout view specifically for use with PDF endpoints if you run into trouble with reuse. It might also be worth looking into using https://www.princexml.com as an alternative to `wkhtmltopdf`, as it is actively developed and supported as a commercial project, though it does also have some similar limitations. There's a cool service called https://docraptor.com that wraps PrinceXML, and does some preprocessing that might improve your situation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate report from model and render pdf while using an end point then will have to generate it at server.

But If you don't want to use pdf generator(wickedpdf or pdfkit) to generate it at server and you have the html then you can use javascript print function and the tag you don't want to include can be hide from printing using media print css.

But its not a good way(secure) if you are generating some kind of certificate since user can edit the html using browser inspect feature and then print.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
@media print {
  .hide_printing {
      display :  none;
  }
}
</style>
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button class="hide_printing" onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```